# Bootstrap panels are pushing each other down if contains data

Tags: html

I'm not sure how to exactly describe this problem, but in conclusion if my Bootstrap panel contains data, then 2nd one is pushed down a bit. I have attached a picture below of it happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdQzE.png)

Panel on left HTML

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-left fw-6" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="panel-heading"> 
      <h3 class="panel-title"><b>Stats</b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="info" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px">data</div>
      <div class="break" style="height: 1px; background-color: black; overflow: hidden; margin: 9px"></div>
      <div class="totalBet" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">data</div>
      <div class="totalProfit" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Panel on right

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-left fw-6" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><b>Transactions</b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped no-footer">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Transaction Hash</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of these elements?

Comment: You would like to see HTML? I'm using somewhat PHP in there as well.

Comment: I edited my first post for HTML.

Comment: @Jordn I tried the codes but wasn't able to reproduce. Is it  possible the behavior is not in code you provided?

Comment: I added code from inspect element actually, I though that reason can't be PHP.

Comment: I too tried reproducing the problem, but I did not seem to run into the same problem. Are you by chance using custom styling for any of these elements?